# Android Studio weird selection of code and how can i undo this

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I need help with this, I used the combination of ctrl + right MouseClick, but seems that now can't UNDO this selection ! I tried to do the same combination of ctrl + right MouseClick but does not work ...
Please help me solve this, how it is called and how do I get rid of this.
Thank you all in advance!

Version of Android Studio: Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Canary 7

[image]

Comment: Try File -> Invalidate Cache & Restart

Comment: Ok, i solved it at restart, but what is it ? i don't think it's a bug

Comment: I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

That's rainbow highlighting (*feature/plugin*), just press `Escape` and it should be gone.

```
Ctrl + Right Click, rainbow highlight
Alt + Right Click, code block focus (darkens everything else)
```